# Selenium on MSD CRM - NavBarOverlay blocks clicks

Tags: selenium, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm trying to use Selenium C# for Automated UI Tests within CRM 2016 SP1.

When trying to click on an element in the ContentIFrame, I often get the exception

```
Element is not clickable at point (743, 496). Other element would receive the click: <div class="navBarOverlay" id="navBarOverlay" style="display: block;"></div>
```

This is due to the navBarOverlay that would still be overlaying.

I've tried many options:

1. `By navBarOverlay = By.Id("navBarOverlay"); 
   wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(navBarOverlay));`
2. `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(elementToClick);`
3. `Thread.Sleep(3000);` before finding the elementToClick
4. `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0,0,10));` before finding the elementToClick

Yet, no success..
How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to workaround this issue.
I hide this div by js injection

```
var navbar = WebDriverManager.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("navBarOverlay"));
WebDriverManager.Driver.ExecuteJavaScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: none')", navbar);
```